# Eclipse Web Service Explorer not displaying list of Objects as response

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap

I have a basic SOAP based web service. I am able to invoke methods and add information to it. But, while retrieving , the data a single class object seems to be perfectly displayed in the WSE browser. But If I have a list of objects, then I am not able to get any response in the body. Not sure, whats going wrong. Even the logs in console don't throw any error.

IS there a better way to view list of objects in WSE ?

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the Source link (to the right of the body) to check if the **SOAP Response Envelope** indeed has multiple objects in it. If it has, you may have encountered a bug in the viewer, if it doesn't - either the service doesn't work as expected, or your Request is not proper.

I tested locally with the following public service (operation `getAll`):

`http://www.predic8.com:8080/crm/CustomerService?wsdl`

It returns a list of many customers (judging from the raw response), but for me WSE only listed a few of the them (and the indentation depicting the hierarchy is wrong), so I guess this view of WSE is not very reliable.

So I'd suggest sticking to the raw XML view in WSE. In my everyday work I prefer using [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org) for service exploring/testing. It is free and gets regularly updated - you might want to check it out.

Good luck!